# Is what I am looking for a scrapbook?

Tags: terminology, material-identification

I'm trying to make a scrapbook. I wanted to buy one from Michaels, or some art supply store but I wanted to know if what I'm looking for exists... the scrapbook I found online at Michaels basically just has ten pages full of laminated papers.

What I want is a book with the same hardcover as a scrapbook except on the inside, there are just pages of white paper because I want to paste photos and I want to write notes in them, and even draw comics in them. I don't want something that looks like a binder.

Does anyone know what I am looking for is called?

Answer (score 4):

How about a **hardbound sketchbook**:
[image]

*this or any other brand

**this is a sticker, the cover is black

***they come in variety of sizes and thicknesses

Comment: If you are going to glue items (paper or other things) to the pages, you may want to take out pages of the book, so there is space for your additions.